# Let's spin the wheel!

Tags: word

I have a friend! (The one everyone seems to have around here) He was on wheel of fortune and did great! Won over $10,000 and a trip to Aruba.
He's now in the bonus round and is ready to win the big prize! Whatever is in the envelope.  He failed though because he just couldn't figure it out.

Being the smart fellow he is, he did his research to find out what the most common letters + vowel are picked from contestants in the bonus round.  What he found through the magic of the internet was

```
C - 64%
M - 59%
D - 57%
A - 48%`
```

His category was `Phrase` and given `RSTLNE` and his chosen letters of `CMDA`, the bonus puzzle result ended up looking like this.

```
  _A_    _N   
_A_    _ _ _
```

He wants to know if any one is slick enough to solve what he could not! There has been many one letter solved puzzles in the history of the game show, so this is a very generous one!

Maybe I can make this a series of my own ;)

**Rules**

- You are allowed ONE guess
- If there is an edit changing your answer, you are automatically disqualified (From getting the green check mark)
- Since I can't really put you on a ten second timer first correct post wins!

Comment: i dont know enough about the wheel of fortune. So just one question. RSTLNE and CMDA are the shown letter and we have to guess from the other remaining letters. right?

Comment: @manshu - Yes! That's correct. All the letters listed are letters shown (or not shown) in the puzzle. So that helps narrow it down. It's much harder with the 10 second pressure, but I'll make due, maybe make revisions based on how this one goes.

Comment: I've edited the tags - once [tag:wheeloffortune] goes away we can switch to [tag:wheel-of-fortune]. Spaces in tag names should be represented by hyphens, but it currently won't let me create [tag:wheel-of-fortune].

Comment: Is it Alex Karras in Webster?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

> WAX ON WAX OFF (from the Karate Kid)

Comment: Bah, couldn't figure out wax. I got to "clap on clap off", but couldn't make it past that.

Comment: Great job! That was pretty quick also!