# Let's spin the wheel! [2]

Tags: word

Let's kick it up a notch from [Let's spin the wheel!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24661/lets-spin-the-wheel)

My friend is again somehow on the game show and has made it to the bonus round yet again! He uses the same strategy as before, but he just plain sucks at this.  He again wants to know if you can figure out at which he failed!

This one is a littler tricker. Given `RSTLNE` and Letters chosen `CMDA` (As most popular)

The puzzle goes like this, The [category](http://wheeloffurtunehistory.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_categories) is `Before and After`

```
C_ _ L _    D _ _    _ _ _ _ T
```

**Rules**

- You are allowed ONE guess
- If there is an edit changing your answer, you are automatically disqualified (From getting the green check mark)
- Since I can't really put you on a ten second timer first correct post wins!
- All the letters listed are letters shown (or not shown) in the puzzle

Comment: When will your friend learn that CMDA probably won't win the prize?

Comment: @Caelan: Yeah, you should choose something more sensible like KXQU!

Comment: Ah, I found this. "CMDA? Try HGDO".

[Wheel of Fortune's Most Frequent Bonus Round Letters](http://williamspaniel.com/2013/02/23/wheel-of-fortunes-most-frequent-bonus-round-letters/)

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole Funny you should say that

Comment: Yeah. If it would work, then we know your answer is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pat, I'd like to solve the puzzle. It's

> `CHILI DOG FIGHT`

Comment: On the show, the contestant would almost certainly not waste time saying "Pat, I'd like to solve the puzzle" - I had to add that to meet the character minimum.

Answer (score 0):

> CHILI DOG NIGHT

My final answer.

Comment: not possible coz the word "night" contains letter 'n' which would have been shown in the question if it were.

Comment: oh, woops. missed adding the 'n' to the exclusion characters in my regex search >.<